# Blackberry .COD Error While uploading in Blackberry App World

Tags: blackberry-storm

The one .COD file gave as 12 COD files and when uploading to App World it gave the following error and does not let me complete upload process!

•   At least one file bundle does not specify a COD/BAR that supports ALL langs (core COD/BAR file)

Please Help me on this issue

Thanks in Advance